# Oracle tnsping.exe - where to get/download it

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I have recently downloaded latest version of Oracle SQL Developer (4.0.0.13), and my idea was that tnsping.exe should go along with it - but this is not the case. Also I was surprised that SQL Developer is provided as archive of files without any kind of installer.
Can somebody advice where to download tnsping.exe?

Comment: It's part of the client (not instant client) and database installations. In SQL Developer you may test a connection using jdbc (new connection -> <insert parameters> -> test.

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov Is the SQL Developer diagnostically equivalent to tnsping?  Or would tnsping be more details and/or take a simpler path, etc. - perhaps bypassing an incorrect SQL Developer configuration?

Comment: @jmsmcfrlnd, a successful tnsping indicates only that the listener is running. A successful jdbc connection test using username, password and service name indicates that the Oracle instance offering the service is accessible and accepts connections - i.e. pretty much all you need to know when testing a connection to a database.

Answer (score 4):

Just install the Oracle client, the tnsping.exe tool comes with it ! it should be in the bin folder.

Comment: I've read elsewhere that the "instant" client does not install it.  Is that true?  Here's one example: http://jasonvogel.blogspot.com/2007/10/oracle-instantclient-tnsping-and-plsql.html

Comment: It's not in my bin folder.  :-(

Comment: Yeah, me neither

Comment: `tnsping` and `lsnrctl` are not in the (SQL Plus) Instant Client, you need a full Client install from the installation media (or get them from an installed sever, which might require more files)

Comment: for testing without tnsping, e.g. from instant client, use **sql plus**: `sqlplus %USERNAME%@%DBSERVER%`

Answer (score 3):

You have to download the *Database Client*. Please note that this is **not** the same package as the Instant Client.

1. Go to the [Oracle DB download page](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html)
2. Click on "See all" on the right column, next to the version and platform of your choice.
3. Scroll down to the "Client" section.
4. You'll have to choose between the *Client home*, or *Client* package. The former only allows an "Administrator" installation type, while the latter lets you choose. [More details here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244064/whats-the-differences-between-the-two-version-of-oracle-client-download-file). But please note that you'll have to run the installer either way: you can't run ~/bin/tnsping successfully until you've run the installer.

Comment: Is there a way to install the tnsping on mac?  It doesn't come with the instant client or instant client support tools.

Comment: I just love the way Oracle names its clients. With that effort they could name all downloadable files on their website as download.zip