# What's the differences between the two version of oracle client download file, "client" and "client home"?

Tags: oracle, connectivity, client

I noticed the Oracle database download page has two groups of clients for users to download. There is a thing called "client" and has 32-bit version and 64-bit version. Also, there is a thing called "client home", which also has both 32-bit and 64-bit version. What are the differences between them? When should I use which?

[image: img]

### Update

The download page URL is https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/oracle19c-linux-5462157.html

Comment: Yes, why would it even be necessary at all to describe the difference in a short sentence on the download page. :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`LINUX.X64_193000_client.zip` is a fully featured installer where you can choose what to install and where, then the installer copies the files to the destination and registers the client.

`LINUX.X64_193000_client_home.zip` is an "image" of and "Administrator" type installation, that you unzip to the destination folder then register it.

[Simplified Image-Based Oracle Database Client Installation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/newft/new-features.html#GUID-D8024846-FCAF-4CBD-92FD-8B6BB1A2D4F3)

> Starting with Oracle Database 19c, the Oracle Database client software
>   is available as an image file for download and installation. You must
>   extract the image software into a directory where you want your Oracle
>   home to be located, and then run the runInstaller script to start the
>   Oracle Database client installation. Oracle Database client
>   installation binaries continue to be available in the traditional
>   format as non-image zip files.
>
> As with Oracle Database and Oracle Grid Infrastructure image file
>   installations, Oracle Database client image installations simplify
>   Oracle Database client installations and ensure best practice
>   deployments.

[About Image-Based Oracle Database Client Installation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lacli/about-image-based-client-installation.html#GUID-C6A77755-DFCD-4FEF-9B41-4CA7908BBAE8)

> Starting with Oracle Database 19c, installation and configuration of
>   Oracle Database Client software is simplified with image-based
>   installation.
>
> To install Oracle Database Client, create the new Oracle home, extract
>   the image file into the newly-created Oracle home, and run the setup
>   wizard to register the Oracle Database product.
>
> You must extract the image software (client_home.zip) into the
>   directory where you want your Oracle Database Client home to be
>   located, and then run the Setup Wizard to start the Oracle Database
>   Client installation and configuration. Oracle recommends that the
>   Oracle home directory path you create is in compliance with the Oracle
>   Optimal Flexible Architecture recommendations.
>
> Using image-based installation, you can install Oracle Database Client
>   32-bit and 64-bit configurations of the Administrator installation
>   type.
>
> As with Oracle Database and Oracle Grid Infrastructure image file
>   installations, Oracle Database Client image installations simplify
>   Oracle Database Client installations and ensure best practice
>   deployments. Oracle Database Client installation binaries continue to
>   be available in the traditional format as non-image zip files.

Comment: Hi Balazs, thanks for your answer. I'm still not sure why image-based installation is considered "better". You still need to extract the file and run an installation script, right? What's your throughs?

Comment: @Justalearner I have almost never used these clients and I don't plan using them. Yeah, you can save a few seconds with the "image" client compared to the full client, great. But still, it is a 2.2 GB "image". That is more than the whole operating system. 620 MB of libs, 500 MB JDK + other Java stuff, 149 MB RDBMS scripts (WTF?), 106 MB `DMU`, 101 MB timezone files (WTF?), 90 MB Perl, 86 MB `afdboot` (WTF? Noone uses AFD even on the servers), and other 100s of MB of unnecessary stuff that we don't need on 99% of client installations. Go for the Instant client. You can even `yum install` it.

Comment: Fully agree. I see no value whatsoever in installing that bloated full client. The instant client is good enough. Especially the latest versions who actually include basic tools like `sqlldr`, 'exp`, `imp`, `expdp`, `impdp` and `sqlplus`. The only thing missing (why?) is the new and improved `sqlcl`. But that is a small additional download.

Comment: And what's more, the instant client is available on all platforms - including MacOS! Even MacOS on PPC which is very much totally super odd!

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind, not true. They don't provide drivers for *BSD. So, not all platforms are supported.

Comment: At the time I'm writing this, instant client does not provide a libocci.so compatible with GCC's C++ ABI >=5. For this, you have to download the "regular client installation", which eventually brings you libocci_gcc53.so. I call that coporatestupid.